# Call python functions from fortran

Tags: python, c, fortran, cpython, f2py

i was wondering if it is possible to call python from fortran.

In particular, my goal is to call some python functions (in which i use tensorflow) by passing a fortran array to the functions directly from fortran.

I know that i can do the opposite: in particular, i have used f2py for binding some subroutines from fortran to python and they work well.

If someone has some ideas, i really will appreciate that.
P.S. If there is the possibility to pass from C using iso_bind_c, someone has some guides/references?
Thank you in advance!

I have tried to look at third party libraries but i have not found something easy to manage, also, i think that doing the binding with c could be great, but i have not found reference/tutorial online.
Also, i have not found online if it is possible to use f2py for calling a python function from fortran.

Comment: One way of doing so might be to simply start a script from Fortran, by executing the Python interpreter with the script, and have the script call back to a f2py interface. The thing is, you can't really build Python into a binary, so it's hard to create something in Python to link against from a Fortran program. (unless you consider Mojo, but I don't think that's the right direction for a generic Fortran interface)  The callback on the interface could retrieve the data from the Fortran application, and pass back the result.

Comment: This is doable, but needs a bit (~30-60 mins) of work. You do not need `f2py` or other third party tools. All you need is `ctypes` Python module and `iso_c_binding` Fortran module. See [this link](https://github.com/cdslaborg/paramonte/blob/08b5ee74e1dc9045fca8fd7d94e3bbc979a3c425/src/interface/Python/paramonte/_ParaMonteSampler.py#L610) for an example Python wrapper and [this link](https://github.com/cdslaborg/paramonte/blob/08b5ee74e1dc9045fca8fd7d94e3bbc979a3c425/src/kernel/ParaMonte%40runParaDRAM.f90#L49) for an example Fortran wrapper interface.

Comment: Depending on which exact tasks you need to do, you might be better of with Fortran libraries, such as https://github.com/modern-fortran/neural-fortran https://github.com/ketetefid/FortNN which also include reading trained networks from keras and similar funcionality.

Comment: Regarding the actual question, calling Python from Fortran, you can call an example in the second duplicate link. But I would be looking for was how to avoid any Python. Try to use the C or C++ API of Tensorflow.

Answer (score 0):

So yes, you can call Python through the C API, but it is complicated enough that you probably don't want to. You'd then probably have to write your own library around the C API for python to use it from Fortran to do the data massaging you need. This is documented here:

https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/intro.html

If you are trying to use TensorFlow, a better approach would probably be the C interface to TensorFlow:

https://www.tensorflow.org/install/lang_c

Good luck!